# Div won't center when using @media

Tags: html, css

I am using @media queries to adjust the content of the website when the window size is changed. I have currently have 2 side-by-side divs and when the window gets below 900px, I move the one on the right below the one on the left.

I can get the bottom div (`Content-Right`) to center without any problem, but I can't seem to get the top one (`Content-Left`) to center. I've posted a link to jsfiddle for my html and css.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<b>JS FIDDLE BELOW</b>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L0nzz8or/

Answer (score 0):

I will assume by top div you mean at the bottom in the section under About EGLT. I deleted the width and used `display:table`. Here are the changes:

```
    /* HOME & CONTACT PAGE STYLES */
.Content-Left {
    display:table;

    float: left;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I wasn't very descriptive. Yes I was referring to Content-Left and Content-Right, but not up in the `/* Home & Contact Page Styles */` section. I was referring to the bottom of the css file where I modify them using `@media` queries

Comment: by "when the window gets below 900px" meaning the user is resizing the window?

Comment: If the user resizes the window or if viewed on something when a smaller screen/window. `@media (max-width: 900px)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a type-o that I didn't see in my CSS.

`.Content-left`

should have been

`.Content-Left`

It was just me overlooking that type-o and having trouble seeing it.